# ArrayList returning NullPointer Exception || Java || OOP

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

Hey can someone please help me understand why I keep getting a null pointer exception while trying to run this?
I was just trying to learn arraylist for a course I am taking.

////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public class Address {
    int houseNumber;
    String roadNumber;
    String areaName;
    String cityName;


public Address(int hn, String rn, String an, String cn){
    this.houseNumber = hn;
    this.roadNumber = rn;
    this.areaName = an;
    this.cityName = cn;
}


public String toString() {
    return "House # " +  this.houseNumber + "\nRoad # " + this.roadNumber + "\n" + this.areaName + "\n" + this.cityName; 
}



}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AddressReferences {

ArrayList<Address> myCollection = new ArrayList<Address>();


public void addAddress (int hn, String rn, String an, String cn) {
    myCollection.add(new Address(hn,rn,an,cn));
}

public void printAddress () {
    for ( Address i : myCollection){
        System.out.println (i);


    }
}
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////

```
public class Test {

static AddressReferences ar;


public static void main(String[] args){

    ar.addAddress(46, "9/a", "Kotol", "Dhaka");
    ar.addAddress(44, "9/a", "Kotol", "Dhaka");
    ar.addAddress(28, "9/a", "Kotol", "Dhaka");
    ar.addAddress(89, "12/a", "Kotol", "Dhaka");
    ar.addAddress(60, "7/a", "Kotol", "Dhaka");


    ar.printAddress();





}
}
```

Comment: You haven't initialized ar to anything. It's  null when you enter your main method.

Answer (score 3):

Fields (instance fields or static fields) are initialized to the "all bits off" version of the kind of value they can hold; for object references, that's `null`. Your `ar` static field starts off with `null`, and you never assign anything to it. Thus, `ar.addAddress(...)` will throw an NPE, because `ar` is `null`.

To fix it, add

```
ar = new AddressReferences();
```

...to `main` before using `ar` for anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here the null point exception doesn't mean `myCollection` is null, it means `ar` is null, so add `ar = new AddressReferences();` into your main function.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    ar = new AddressReferences();

    ar.addAddress(46, "9/a", "Kotol", "Dhaka");
    ar.addAddress(44, "9/a", "Kotol", "Dhaka");
    ar.addAddress(28, "9/a", "Kotol", "Dhaka");
    ar.addAddress(89, "12/a", "Kotol", "Dhaka");
    ar.addAddress(60, "7/a", "Kotol", "Dhaka");

    ar.printAddress();

}
```